# How to use this code in html javascript ? clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I found this code (Example https://jsfiddle.net/uxo27cq0/)

```js
function displaytickets(){
  var $panel = $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-3 panel panel-default')
    $panel.append($('<div><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>').addClass('panel-heading'))
    $panel.append($('<div>Panel content</div>').addClass('panel-body'));
    $('body').append($panel);
    
   // let's assume your ajax returns 4 tickets
    var data = {
     'tickets' : [
       {'description' : 'Description_1', 'status': 'Status_1', 'subject': 'Subject_1' },
       {'description' : 'Description_2', 'status': 'Status_2', 'subject': 'Subject_2' },
       {'description' : 'Description_3', 'status': 'Status_3', 'subject': 'Subject_3' },
       {'description' : 'Description_4', 'status': 'Status_4', 'subject': 'Subject_4' }
      ]
    };
    
    for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
     var new_panel = $panel.clone(); // note the use of .clone()
      new_panel.find('.panel-title').text(data.tickets[i].subject);
      new_panel.find('.panel-body').text(data.tickets[i].description);
      $('body').append(new_panel);
  }
}

displaytickets();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I do not know how to make it work in html in the following way:

```html
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body>

// div here

<script type="text/javascript">

// i put the code here

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

obviously it did not work, so, if someone can tell me how it should be, it would solve my problem completely

Thank you!!!

Comment: what is the problem and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Jess Yerena the code snippet is good but  we need to know what is the problem, what have you tried and where you are stuck in more detail.

Comment: you can check out  this https://jsfiddle.net/8c95b6y7/

Comment: but I want to get the html elements out of the code so I can edit them freely and then call them with the id or otherwise. 
(see my last response)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<style>
</style>
<body>

// div here
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displaytickets() {
    var $panel = $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-3 panel panel-default')
                 $panel.append($('<div><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>').addClass('panel-heading'))
                 $panel.append($('<div>Panel content</div>').addClass('panel-body'));
$('body').append($panel);

   // let's assume your ajax returns 4 tickets
     var data = {
 'tickets' : [
   {'description' : 'Description_1', 'status': 'Status_1', 'subject': 'Subject_1' },
   {'description' : 'Description_2', 'status': 'Status_2', 'subject': 'Subject_2' },
   {'description' : 'Description_3', 'status': 'Status_3', 'subject': 'Subject_3' },
   {'description' : 'Description_4', 'status': 'Status_4', 'subject': 'Subject_4' }
     ]
};

for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
 var new_panel = $panel.clone(); // note the use of .clone()
  new_panel.find('.panel-title').text(data.tickets[i].subject);
  new_panel.find('.panel-body').text(data.tickets[i].description);
  $('body').append(new_panel);
 }
}

displaytickets();

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked for me, but I try that the html elements are out of the javascript code to be able to freely edit, something like this: (see my last answer)

Answer (score 0):

@Jess Yerena, here is what you need - create two files and run index.html:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function displaytickets() {
  var $panel = $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-3 panel panel-default');
  $panel.append(
    $('<div><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>').addClass('panel-heading')
  );
  $panel.append($('<div>Panel content</div>').addClass('panel-body'));
  $('body').append($panel);

  // let's assume your ajax returns 4 tickets
  var data = {
    tickets: [
      {
        description: 'Description_1',
        status: 'Status_1',
        subject: 'Subject_1'
      },
      {
        description: 'Description_2',
        status: 'Status_2',
        subject: 'Subject_2'
      },
      {
        description: 'Description_3',
        status: 'Status_3',
        subject: 'Subject_3'
      },
      { description: 'Description_4', status: 'Status_4', subject: 'Subject_4' }
    ]
  };

  for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
    var new_panel = $panel.clone(); // note the use of .clone()
    new_panel.find('.panel-title').text(data.tickets[i].subject);
    new_panel.find('.panel-body').text(data.tickets[i].description);
    $('body').append(new_panel);
  }
}

displaytickets();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:enter code here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  displaytickets();
});
function displaytickets() {
  var $panel = $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-3 panel panel-default')
  $panel.append($('<div><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>').addClass('panel-heading'))
  $panel.append($('<div>Panel content</div>').addClass('panel-body'));
  $('#div-clone-here').append($panel);

  // let's assume your ajax returns 4 tickets
  var data = {
    'tickets': [{
        'description': 'Description_1',
        'status': 'Status_1',
        'subject': 'Subject_1'
      },
      {
        'description': 'Description_2',
        'status': 'Status_2',
        'subject': 'Subject_2'
      },
      {
        'description': 'Description_3',
        'status': 'Status_3',
        'subject': 'Subject_3'
      },
      {
        'description': 'Description_4',
        'status': 'Status_4',
        'subject': 'Subject_4'
      }
    ]
  };

  for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
    var new_panel = $panel.clone(); // note the use of .clone()
    new_panel.find('.panel-title').text(data.tickets[i].subject);
    new_panel.find('.panel-body').text(data.tickets[i].description);
    $('#div-clone-here').append(new_panel);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-clone-here">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<style>
</style>
<body>

// div here
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displaytickets() {
    var $panel = $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-3 panel panel-default')
                 $panel.append($('<div><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>').addClass('panel-heading'))
                 $panel.append($('<div>Panel content</div>').addClass('panel-body'));
$('body').append($panel);

   // let's assume your ajax returns 4 tickets
     var data = {
 'tickets' : [
   {'description' : 'Description_1', 'status': 'Status_1', 'subject': 'Subject_1' },
   {'description' : 'Description_2', 'status': 'Status_2', 'subject': 'Subject_2' },
   {'description' : 'Description_3', 'status': 'Status_3', 'subject': 'Subject_3' },
   {'description' : 'Description_4', 'status': 'Status_4', 'subject': 'Subject_4' }
     ]
};

for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
 var new_panel = $panel.clone(); // note the use of .clone()
  new_panel.find('.panel-title').text(data.tickets[i].subject);
  new_panel.find('.panel-body').text(data.tickets[i].description);
  $('body').append(new_panel);
 }
}

displaytickets();

</script>

</html>
```

but I want to get the html elements out of the code so I can edit them freely and then call them with the id or otherwise.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<style>
 .panel {
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: none;
 }
 .heading {
   background-color: purple;
   width: 100%;

 }
 .panel-body {
   background-color: green;
 }
</style>
<body>

<div id="container" class="panel">
<div id="header" class="heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>
<div id="content" class="panel-body">Panel content</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function displaytickets() {
 var $panel = $('container')
 $panel.append($('header'));
 $panel.append($('content'));
 $('body').append(($panel));

 // let's assume your ajax returns 4 tickets
 var data = {
  'tickets': [
   {'description' : 'Description_1', 'status': 'Status_1', 'subject': 'Subject_1' },
   {'description' : 'Description_2', 'status': 'Status_2', 'subject': 'Subject_2' },
   {'description' : 'Description_3', 'status': 'Status_3', 'subject': 'Subject_3' },
   {'description' : 'Description_4', 'status': 'Status_4', 'subject': 'Subject_4' }
     ]
 };

 for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
  var new_panel = $panel.clone(); // note the use of .clone()
  new_panel.find('.panel-title').text(data.tickets[i].subject);
  new_panel.find('.panel-body').text(data.tickets[i].description);
  $('body').append(new_panel);
 }
}

displaytickets();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yerana: You can refer the answer given by Carl Kevin Garcia.